# How to take mysql database backup using whenever gem in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using the **whenever** gem for taking the mysql database backup, I used cron job for this but when I run a shell command using `system"mysqldump -u root -ppassword app_production > /output_path/app_production.sql"`,this will run only once after running `whenever --update-crontab store` command on terminal.

My schedule.rb is:

```
set :output, "/output_path/app_production.sql"
set :environment, 'production'

every 59.minute do
  system"mysqldump -u root -ppassword app_production > /path/app_production.sql"
  # runner "MyModel.some_method"
  # rake "some:great:rake:task"
end
```

Am I missing something in this ?

Answer (score 1):

There may be a few things to check to make sure that this is running.  Are you sure that `app_production.sql` contains a correct dump? Or is the file created without any content?  Also try using `command` instead of `system`.  I think `command` is a whenever command where `system` is ruby.

```
every 59.minutes do
  command "mysqldump -u root -ppassword app_production > /path/app_production.sql"
  # runner "MyModel.some_method"
  # rake "some:great:rake:task"
end
```

UPDATE:

you can also look at the [backup gem](https://github.com/meskyanichi/backup) for backup purposes.  It has a lot of features including notifications so I suggest you look at it.

Comment: if i am using command "mysqldump -u root -ppassword app_production > /path/app_production.sql" this, we get always empty file.

Comment: what happens when you try `mysqldump -u root -ppassword app_production > /path/app_production.sql` in a terminal? make sure that it runs properly first.

Comment: When i run mysqldump -u root -ppassword app_production > /path/app_production.sql in terminal, i get backup of mysql database.

Comment: try running the command generated by whenever in the crontab.  type in `whenever` in your terminal and copy and paste the command generated by whenever.  see if that works or if it throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

I already get this problem. the solution is :

```
set :output, "/output_path/app_production.sql"
set :environment, 'production'
every 59.minute do
   command "mysqldump -u root -ppassword app_production"
   # runner "MyModel.some_method"
   # rake "some:great:rake:task"
end
```

after running the command, take a look now at the ouput  file

I hope that it can help you :)